# Не работает регулярное выражение в js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Что бы я не вводил, приложение переходит ко второму окну

```
n = new Array();
f = new Array();
x = true;
while (x) {
    name = prompt("Введіть ім'я");
    if (name.match("/[А-Яа-я]/")) {alert("error");
        return false;}
    if (name==null) {x = false; }
    firstname=prompt("Введіть фамілію");
    if (firstname == null) x = false;
    n.push(name);
    f.push(firstname);
}
if (!x) {
    for(var i=0;i<n.length-1,i<f.length-1;i++){
        document.write("Імя: " + n[i] +" Прізвище " + f[i]+"<br />");
    }
}
```

Comment: сейчас в match передается строка, а должно быть регулярное выражение: для исправления нужно просто убрать кавычки

Answer (score 1):

Надо понимать разницу между "Не работает в языке X." и "Не знаю регулярок, что не так?".
Проверка должна быть такая:

```
/^[а-яё]+$/i.test(name)
```

Чем решение выше больше подходит:

1. Функция `RegExp#test` лишь проверяет что текст подходит под регулярку, что выгоднее и быстрее того же `RegExp#match`.
2. Конструкции `^` и `$` говорят что проверка должна быть от начала до конца строки, а не удовлетворяться одним верным символом в во всей строке (`12$%5%8ф1%`).
3. Буква `ё` не входит в диапазон `а-я` (особенности разворачивания диапазона, абшибка ИМХО).

Comment: я уже понял. Спасибо

Comment: Спасибо тут выражается плюсом и приёмом ответа.

Comment: а почему проверка должна быть такая?

Comment: @Grundy, намёк понял, но не могу же я полностью весь скрипт переписать на человеческий язык :) Поэтому только регулярка.

Comment: @Other, вообще, конечно, можешь :) но нужно хотя бы добавить описание чем именно отличается то что ты привел, от того, что в вопросе. Я, что-то, кроме буквы `ё` и допустимости `name==null` не вижу отличий

Comment: @Grundy, довольны ли Вы, сударь?

Comment: @Other, уже лучше, но второй пункт какой-то спорный: в коде в вопросе, если нашлась хотя бы одна русская буква - выкидывало алерт с ошибкой и возвращало `false`, а в твоем случае - нужно чтобы были только русские буквы

Comment: @Grundy, пожалуй, Вы правы. Но, думаю, пусть будет возможность убрать и знать об этом, чем убрать и оставить во тьме невежества :)